# Why is table not respecting my CSS command?

Tags: html, css

Here is a part of my HTML code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/mystyle.css" %}"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Here are your patient records:</h1>
        <h2>Go to /formpage to fill the form</h2>

        {% if patients %}
            <table>
              <thead>
                <th>Patient Name</th>
                <th>Identity Document Number</th>
                <th>Date of Birth</th>
                <th>Date Case Confirmed</th>
                <th>Case Number</th>
              </thead>

              {% for pat in patients %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ pat.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ pat.idn }}</td>
                  <td>{{ pat.date_of_birth }}</td>
                  <td>{{ pat.confirm_day }}</td>
                  <td>{{ pat.case_no }}</td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
          </table>
```

I want to edit the table according to my CSS rules.

```
h1{
  color: red;
}

table, td, th{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

However, the table does not respect the changes from CSS. Funny thing is, h1 header is actually following the CSS rule and is red.
What am I missing?

Comment: what do you expect from the code and what is your actual output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to inspect element the table and check if your `border: 1px solid black;` applies to the element (on inspect element window, on css box, make sure the text isn't in strikethrough), if the text is in strikethrough, try adding `!important` keyword next to `black` and before `;`.

Answer (score -1):

Your CSS gets applied to the table elements, you can check it with the developer tools in your browser.

Also a running example of your table:

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<h1>Here are your patient records:</h1>
<h2>Go to /formpage to fill the form</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Patient Name</th>
    <th>Identity Document Number</th>
    <th>Date of Birth</th>
    <th>Date Case Confirmed</th>
    <th>Case Number</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>idn</td>
      <td>date_of_birth</td>
      <td>confirm_day</td>
      <td>case_no</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>idn</td>
      <td>date_of_birth</td>
      <td>confirm_day</td>
      <td>case_no</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>idn</td>
      <td>date_of_birth</td>
      <td>confirm_day</td>
      <td>case_no</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```